# onpress event for icon in TabNavigator (react native with react-navigation)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an icon that i include in a tab navigator as per below:

```
const SearchTabBarIcon = ({ tintColor }) => (
      <IconMCI
        name="account-search"
        size={45}
        color={tintColor}
        onPress={() => console.log('HELP!!')}
      />
    );
```

....then my tabNavigator looks like this:

```
const SignedInTabNav = TabNavigator(
  {
    Profile: {
      screen: Profile,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Me',
        tabBarIcon: ProfileTabBarIcon,
      },
    },
    Search: {
      screen: Search,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Search',
        tabBarIcon: SearchTabBarIcon,
      },
    },

    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    animationEnabled: false,
  }, 
);
```

The console.log is fired when I click the icon, however the native functionality of the tabNavigator is lost.
How can I fire the onPress event but also maintain the navigation functionality?

Ive heard I should perhaps "***add the props of navigation to my component in the render***".
The render function of App.js looks like this:

```
 render() {
    const Layout = createRootNavigator(this.props.isAuthenticated);

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#F8F8FF' }}>
        <Layout />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

....and the function createRootNavigator looks like this

```
  const createRootNavigator = (authenticated = false) =>
      createSwitchNavigator(
        {
          SignedInTabNav: {
            screen: SignedInTabNav,
          },
          SignedOutStackNav: {
            screen: SignedOutStackNav,
          },
        },
        {

          initialRouteName: authenticated ? 'SignedInTabNav' : 'SignedOutStackNav',
        },
      );
```

....so where/how do I add the navigation prop in the render for App.js?...and will it be passed down through createRootNavigator.....and further through createSwitchNavigator....and finally passed into SignedInTabNav (TabNavigator) where the Search icon is referenced?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **tabBarOnPress** callback to handle press events as an additional option, like this:

```js
const SignedInTabNav = TabNavigator(
  {
    Profile: {
      screen: Profile,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Me',
        tabBarIcon: ProfileTabBarIcon,
      },
    },
    Search: {
      screen: Search,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Search',
        tabBarIcon: SearchTabBarIcon,
        tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation, defaultHandler }) => {
          console.log('this will be fired just before nagivation happens')
          defaultHandler() // if you omit this, navigation will not happen
        }
      },
    },

    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    animationEnabled: false,
  }, 
);
```

Comment: Hi - This is a good idea in concept.....but I still need a way to pass the navigation props to my TabNavigator function, so I can use it in my tabBarOnPress event handler (appears that the navigation prop is required for the defaultHandler function).....any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this could be the solution? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Comment: In my app, i created a NavigationWithoutProp service to handle navigation in places where I don't have access to navigation prop (for example, i navigate to different screens when user opens a notification, based on different notification type). Maybe you could create this service and try to use it into tabNavigator. Let me know if this helps you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use the 'didFocus' event from reactNavigation

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/function-after-focusing-screen.html

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.focusListener = navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
      // The screen is focused
      // Call any action
    });
  }
```